# Service for comparing things in a grid and rating them

Tags: web-apps

I am looking for a web app/service where you can create a grid to compare several similar items and then people can vote to rate the items in the grid. It should also be possible to sort and filter the items by rating and other criterias.

Somewhat like [Django Packages](http://www.djangopackages.com), but one where you can create your own comparison grids and not just for software package.

It *must* be a service. I do not want to host it myself.